# How to use IPV6 Addresses in OpenSSL Certificate 'nameConstraints'

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to create a Root CA for my local development environment, so I can set my local development certificates as trusted in Firefox. However, setting a Root CA without any constraints as trusted is not optimal security wise, in case anyone ever gets hold of the private key. Therefore, I want to use 'nameConstraints', so the CA can never be used to issue certificates for non-local addresses.

However, I don't understand the correct syntax for constraining the certificate to an Ipv6 localhost address. I've tried the following:

```bash
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout development.ca.key \
      -subj '/C=NL/O=Local Environment/OU=Development/CN=Local Environment Development Root' \
      -addext "basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0" \
      -addext "subjectKeyIdentifier = hash" \
      -addext "keyUsage = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign" \
      -addext "nameConstraints = permitted;DNS:.development.local, permitted;IP:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255, permitted;IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/128" \
      -out development.ca.crt
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
Error checking extensions defined using -addext
40B73E1D9B7F0000:error:11000076:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:bad ip address:../crypto/x509/v3_san.c:556:value=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/128
40B73E1D9B7F0000:error:11000080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf_int:error in extension:../crypto/x509/v3_conf.c:48:section=default, name=nameConstraints, value=permitted;DNS:.development.local, permitted;IP:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255, permitted;IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/128
```

I've also tried variations like:

- 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001/128
- ::1/128

All of these generate the error. All examples online (e.g. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man5/x509v3_config.html) seem to only mention ipv4 addresses.

Does anyone know if it's possible to add IPV6 name constraints, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: You need a _mask_; /128 is not a mask -- it is a prefix-length that many programs can turn _into_ a mask, but OpenSSL does not. Use `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dave_thompson_085, this works as expected. My confusion was probably because almost all examples of IPV6 addresses seem to use prefix-lengths in favor of masks. I've added an answer, and referred to your comment there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@dave_thompson_085 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060871/how-to-use-ipv6-addresses-in-openssl-certificate-nameconstraints/77082423#comment135850709_77060871):

> You need a mask; /128 is not a mask -- it is a prefix-length that many programs can turn into a mask, but OpenSSL does not. Use 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff.

I can confirm the following works:

```bash
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout development.ca.key \
      -subj '/C=NL/O=Local Environment/OU=Development/CN=Local Environment Development Root' \
      -addext "basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0" \
      -addext "subjectKeyIdentifier = hash" \
      -addext "keyUsage = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign" \
      -addext "nameConstraints = permitted;DNS:.development.local, permitted;IP:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255, permitted;IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff" \
      -out development.ca.crt
```